# json cant extract child with php

Tags: php, json

I try to get two pieces of information from a json file: The "Principal" and the WiFiMAC. I need it to export the name and the MAC to export in a database.

```
{
"messages":
          {"message":"150 devices(s) returned."},
           "devices":
                   {"device":
            [
                    {"@id":"121","uuid":"xxx-xxx-xxxxxxxxx-xxx-x-xxxxx","principal":"John Rambo","blockReason":0,"clientId":"anything","compliance":0,"countryCode":49,"countryId":68,"countryName":"Germany","details":
                            [
                            {"entry":[
                                    {"key":"Model","value":"anything"},
                                    {"key":"AvailableDeviceCapacity","value":57.360877990722656},
{"key":"WiFiMAC","value":"123456789012"}]}]}]}}
```

and many more keys.

I can extract the principal like this:

```
$json = file_get_contents("test.xml");
$json = json_decode($json);
echo $json->messages->message;
echo $json->devices->device[1]->principal;
```

but I get no chance to extract the WiFiMAC.
I need this for any device in the json, I think I can load every device with a foreach... but the first is the extract the WiFiMAC.

Comment: please provide proper JSON string ...

Answer (score 0):

Have replicated your requirement, visit the link below:
http://codepad.org/MhgkTloe

```
$ret = json_decode($json, true);
// the principal
echo $ret['devices']['device'][0]['principal'];
// This is the path to WiFiMac
echo $ret['devices']['device'][0]['details'][0]['entry'][2]['key'];
```